# C# Dataset DataTable position from DB

Tags: c#, sql-server

In all my years of C# development (10+) there has always been the dilemma of knowing which table is where in a dataset that is retrieved from the database. I didn't find anything recently in my searches but it's possible I missed it.

Typically I would use the index but I have to know the table order in the stored procedure.

I was thinking if there was a way to give a table a name in the stored procedure and then I could use that name in the code as apposed to the index and then the stored procedure could theoretically be changed without breaking anything. But I can't find a way to assign a name to a table.

So has someone a solution, if there is, to know what table is where in a dataset that is gotten from the SQL Server database?

Edit to see if I can explain better with an example:

In a stored procedure, I query and have 4 tables that I return (tables: *apples*, *oranges*, *pears*, *peaches*)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetTables AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * from apples ;
    SELECT * from oranges ;
    SELECT * from pears ;
    SELECT * from peaches ;
END
```

In the code, all 4 tables are now in a `DataSet`.

To get table 2 (`DataTable`), I would generally do

```
var dt2 = dataset.tables[1]; //oranges
```

Now someone comes along and says we need strawberries and I'm going to put that between apples and oranges, so our dataset now is

```
apples, strawberries, oranges, pears, peaches
```

In the code I'm expecting *oranges*, but now I'm getting *strawberries*.

I'm looking for a way to label the results so that if *strawberries* are added, my code will always be *oranges*.

Comment: Some code examples would really help here. I don't know what you're asking. Are you querying a list of tables then using the result to query a dataset?

Comment: @JacobH your over thinking this. Your looking at the bark on the trees as apposed to the forest. :)

Comment: @jdweng Queries can return an arbitrary number of result sets, not just one or nothing. The `USE` instruction switches databases, not "tables". While `DataSet`s are an obsolete thing of the past and better tools are available now, they can very well hold all the result of a query, including multple tables.

Comment: @Alejandro can you provide a list/single item than a dataset for multiple tables from a SP that would be better?

Comment: @MicahMontoya Sure you can consolidate all the results into a single table, as long as they share the same structure (adding some sort of discriminator field). But if their columns differ, you're going to need multiple result sets. I don't think either is bad, you just need to be careful in how you handle them afterwards.

Comment: This just isn't possible. Queries don't return tables, they return result sets. How would you give a name to a result set that joins 10 tables?

Comment: @MicahMontoya I took the liberty of providing an hypotetical stored procedure returning 4 tables, correct me if I've got it wrong.

Comment: @Alejandro looks fine. Thx.

Comment: @SeanLange You are right. Most developers I know don't talk result sets. It's usually always tables in the result set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing is right, there are no such things as a "named" result set. Basically when a query returns multiple result sets, the datareader returns them in the very same order, and that's what you must rely on.

Calling a stored procedure ultimately needs knowledge of the client program of the input parameters and the expected result set, effectively this creates a coupling between them, as adding an extra result set in between will break unsuspecting clients, the same as removing or reordering them.

Your concern is correct and well-founded. There are some things you must preserve if your change server-side code if the client code is going to stay the same, among them:

- Input parameter types and names, and depending on how you call your SP, also ordering.
- Result set ordering. New ones can be added as long as they're at the end.
- Column names and, depending how the client accesses them, also its order.
- Row order could be important sometimes.

Other things are like internal implementation details and can be changed at will, as long as they don't change the externally visible inputs and outputs.

**Edit after OP edit**

Since going from returning **apples, oranges, pears, peaches** to returning **apples, strawberries , oranges, pears, peaches** adds a result set in the middle, code that relies on the ordering will fail, making it a *breaking change*. The correct thing to do in such a case is to return **apples, oranges, pears, peaches, strawberries** instead.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking the same thing since nothing was discovered in my searches (MSDN, google, etc.)